# Role of position: absolute in this CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

While I've been learning more about CSS, I've been looking at this [post on creating a drop-down menu](http://css-snippets.com/drop-down-navigation) and the [code demo](http://lisacatalano.github.io/dropdown/) here.

Reading how `position: absolute;` should behave as described in the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#abs-pos), it states:

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings).

and the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#containing-block) is determined this way:

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a position other than static... If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the initial containing block.

In the linked post on the menu, it doesn't explain how the absolute positioning works in this case. First, there are no offsets to position the elements. And, unless I'm missing something, it looks to me as if no other page elements have anything other than the default `position: static;`

My expectation then isn't that the dropdowns using `position:absolute;` would appear as part of the dropdown, but should maybe be positioned with respect to the page instead, so perhaps appear in the top-left corner instead, completely out of flow.

My assumption's wrong. So, how is the positioning directly below the parent menu item explained?

HTML:

```
<body class="news">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #1@@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #2@@@</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}

/*******************************************
   Style menu for larger screens

   Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
   or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add `position: relative;` to `nav li` and `position: absolute;` to all submenu `<ul>` elements (i.e. the `nav li ul` selector). This anchors the submenu lists to their corresponding list elements in the main menu.

Then add `top` and `left` values (in px) to those submenu `<ul>` elements to finetune their position in relation to their parent elements (i.e. the `li ul`)